# systemd not waiting for my service unit to finish before starting the next one

Tags: docker, systemd

Here are my two units:

```
 - name: percona_db.service
   command: start
   enable: true
   content: |
     [Unit]
     Description=Percona db
     After=docker.service
     Requires=docker.service

     [Service]
     ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/docker start -a mysql_datastore || /usr/bin/docker run -d -v /var/lib/mysql --name mysql_datastore -p 23:23 busybox'
     ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/docker start -a mypercona || /usr/bin/docker run -i -t --volumes-from mysql_datastore --name="mypercona" -p 3306:3306 --rm percona'
     ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop mypercona

     [Install]
     WantedBy=multi-user.target
 - name: php_fpm.service
   command: start
   enable: true
   content: |
     [Unit]
     Description=php fpm
     After=percona_db.service
     Requires=percona_db.service

     [Service]
     ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/docker start -a myphpfpm_53 || /usr/bin/docker run --name myphpfpm_53 -dit -p 9000:9000  --link mypercona:db phpfpm_53'
     ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop myphpfpm_53

     [Install]
     WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My problem is the following:
The docker container launched by percona_db.service can sometimes takes a long time to be loaded (if it's the fist load, it will create db and add data, it can take some time).
The php_fpm service needs percona service to start as I link them together.
And, even though I specified:

```
 After=percona_db.service
 Requires=percona_db.service
```

systemd tries to start the phpfpm service before percona_db service is finsihed and throws an error saying percona container doesnt exists :/.

What am I doing wrong?
Or what can I do to make it work? (maybe make phpfpm service wait artificially? Is it possible with systemd?)

thank you !

Comment: Do you have just `php_fpm.service` listed in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` or both `percona_db.service` and `php_fpm.service`. It should not matter, since `After=percona_db.service` in the `php_fpm.service` should control the order in which they are started if both are listed, but it would be worth trying to remove the `percona_db.service` from `multi-user.target.wants` to see if that will force correct ordering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your percona_db is a long running process, so systemd would fork a subprocess and let it run, and assume all is well, and go ahead start php_fpm.

This is also common for a lot of services, i.e., start-up script returned before the application is actually ready. The best way is to write a program to check the status of percona_db and it would be waiting until percona_db is ready, and then, add a line *ExecStartPre=<your_check_program>* .. in your php_fpm service file.

Comment: This answer provides a work-around. To understand what really happens, read @Umut answer and the link it provides.

Answer (score 13):

Every .service file has a Type=[1] field. The Type= field tells systemd when it should accept that your service is ready so it can start follow-up services.

You have not specified Type= in your service file under [Service] section. Because of that systemd sets the default type which is Type=simple. In simple case, systemd will start your process that is specified with ExecStart and assume all will go right. At this point systemd considers your service as ready.

You would want to set Type=oneshot in your percona_db.service.

[1] - http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html